# Reformat pieces of expressions in SymPy to prevent distribution of constant coefficient

Tags: python, sympy

Suppose I define the following expression:

`poly1 = 6/(25*(x + 3)) + 1/(5*(x + 3)**2)`

which prints out:

`6/(25*x + 75) + 1/(5*(x + 3)**2)`

I have two questions regarding this expression. Firstly, is there a way to keep the expression in the format in which I entered it? In particular, is there something that I could do in order to leave the denominator of the first term as `25*(x + 3)`?

Secondly, if I have the expression in its printed form, what is the best way to break apart the expression, reformat the denominator of the first term, and then put it back together? Ideally I would be able to just dig into the expression using a series of `args` calls to get to the denominator of the first term, and then use the factor function to factor it properly, as in `poly1.args[0].args[1].args[0].factor()`. The problem is that, since the Tuples making up the expression are immutable, I can't just replace a piece of `poly1` with the expression computed above. Is there a better way to substitute in the factored polynomial than just rebuilding the whole expression from scratch?

Note: I'd rather not use the `subs()` method, because that searches the entire expression, and it seems like there might be cases where you would want to be very specific about the different pieces you modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic distribution of constants is a [touchy subject](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/4596). There is an option to disable it as follows:

```
from sympy.core.evaluate import distribute
with distribute(False):
    poly1 = 6/(25*(x+3)) + 1/(5*(x + 3)**2)
    print(poly1)  #  6/(25*(x + 3)) + 1/(5*(x + 3)**2)
```

Or you can wrap 25 in `UnevaluatedExpr` to prevent its interaction with other terms.

```
poly1 = 6/(UnevaluatedExpr(25)*(x+3)) + 1/(5*(x + 3)**2)
print(poly1)  #  6*25**(-1)/(x + 3) + 1/(5*(x + 3)**2)
```

Or use the un-evaluated product (Mul) in the denominator:

```
poly1 = 6/Mul(25, x+3, evaluate=False) + 1/(5*(x + 3)**2)
print(poly1)  #  6/(25*(x + 3)) + 1/(5*(x + 3)**2)
```

Or wrap the denominator in `factor_terms` -- a gentler form of `factor` which does the job of extracting the coefficient without messing too much with the expression.

```
poly1 = 6/factor_terms(25*(x+3)) + 1/(5*(x + 3)**2)
print(poly1)  #  6/(25*(x + 3)) + 1/(5*(x + 3)**2)
```

Or cheat by introducing a symbol that looks like a number:

```
c25 = symbols('25')
poly1 = 6/(c25*(x+3)) + 1/(5*(x + 3)**2)
print(poly1)  #  1/(5*(x + 3)**2) + 6/(25*(x + 3))
```

Suggested reading: [Prevent expression evaluation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#prevent-expression-evaluation)

The second question, about targeted replacement, is hard to answer in this generality. One has to [recurse through the expression tree](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html), rebuilding `expr` as `expr.func(*args)` where `args` are `expr.args`, possibly modified. The main issue is how you will know that *this* instance of `25*x + 75` is the one that should be replaced.

Comment: And that about covers it! Great summary of methods.

As for the second question, take a look at the not-oft-mentioned traversaltools in simplify.

Comment: @smichr, the documentation for traversaltools seems sparse, so just to clarify: `use()`applies some function to every argument at a given level on the expression tree? Is there a way to specify one particular node of the graph (i.e. one argument of the expression) to apply some function to?


@Welcome to Stack Overflow, I'm looking for something like the `ReplacePart` function from Mathematica -- something which replaces a given node on the expression graph, rather than recursing through the graph in order to search for something that matches a particular form.

Comment: Sorry...I meant `epathtools` in the same folder.