# Is there a way where I can output the expression without evaluation jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sympy

Inside a jupyter notebook I created an expression, now that expression I want to display the full expression without evaluating, how can I achieve that.

```
     from sympy import *

     x,y,z,a,b,c,d = symbols('x,y,z,a,b,c,d')
     pr = (1/a+1/b)**-1
     display(pr))
     init_printing()
```

Comment: I think you want `UnevaluatedExpr` in sympy...

Comment: Partially [python - Reformat pieces of expressions in SymPy to prevent distribution of constant coefficient - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53243409/reformat-pieces-of-expressions-in-sympy-to-prevent-distribution-of-constant-coef)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to wrap a term in `UnevaluatedExpr`:

```
In [29]: (UnevaluatedExpr(1/a)+1/b)**-1
Out[29]: 
       -1
⎛1   1⎞  
⎜─ + ─⎟  
⎝a   b⎠
```

In this case `with sympy.core.evaluate(False):` doesn't work.

This is already well-explained in [Advanced Expression Manipulation - Prevent expression evaluation — SymPy 1.7.1 documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#prevent-expression-evaluation).